# Hibernate and boolean mapping from sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, javabeans

i have a native sql query to transform (aliasToBean) to a bean with a boolean value.

My query can be something like this:

```
select val IS NOT NULL as boolValue , ...
```

or this:

```
select 1=0 as boolValue, ...
```

I can not understand how to let Hibernate knows that my bean.boolValue is a Boolan because I get errors in type conversion, in the first case I get a java.math.BigInteger in the second a java.lang.Integer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Hibernate that this column is a boolean, with the [SQLQuery.addScalar() method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29).

Comment: Thank you but how to tell if I have a namedQuery instead of a runtime query?

Comment: There are corresponding return-scalar XML elements, as the javadoc I linked to indicates.